# Nested $promise undefined error

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am getting the error `Cannot read property of '$promise' of undefined.`

Here is the code that is throwing it:

```
var myPromise = sharedDataService.getData($scope.entityId).$promise;
resolvePromise(myPromise, 'entityData');
```

the `resolvePromise` method:

```
function resolvePromise(promise, resultObject){
    promise.then(function(response){
        $scope[resultObject] = result;
    });
    promise['catch'](function(error){
        //error callback
    });
    promise['finally'](function(){
        //finally callback
    });
```

sharedDataService looks like this:

```
var publicInterface = {
    getData: getData
};

var storedData;
function getData(entityId) {
    if(storedData.entityId === entityId){
        return storedData;
    }else{
        var entityDataPromise = dataAccessService.getEntityData(entityId).$promise;
        entityDataPromise.then(function (response) {
            storedData = response;
            return storedData ;
         });
         entityDataPromise['catch'](function(error) {
              //throw error;
         });
         entityDataPromise['finally'](function(done) {
             //do finally
         });
    }
 }
 return publicInterface;
```

finally, the dataAccessService:

```
 var publicInterface = {
     getEntityData: getEntityData
 }

 var entityData = $resource(apiUrl + 'Entity', {}, {
     'getEntityData': {
         method: 'GET',
         url: apiUrl + 'Entity/getEntityDataById'
      }
 }

 function getEntityData(entityId){
     return entityData.getEntityData({entityId: entityId})
 }

 return publicInterface;
```

the original promise is throwing an error.  When I put breakpoints various places, I can see my data is being returned sometimes.  The functionality of sharedDataService is almost one of a chaching service.

Why is my original promise returning undefined?

Comment: `getData()`  doesn't return anything when the `if` is false. A `return` inside a callback doesn't return to the outer function

Comment: @charlietfl There is a line in there that says `return storedData` in the `.then` of the else statement?

Comment: That only returns to `then()` ... it does not return to `getData()`. You are going to need to return a promise for both conditions of `if`

Comment: @charlietfl I'm don't fully understand :(

Answer (score 1):

Your `getData()` method doesn't have a `return` when `if` is false. So you would need to return `entitiyDataPromise`.

But, that would mean one condition returns a promise and the other returns an object

So both conditions need to return a promise and we can use `$q` for the first condition

```
function getData(entityId) {
    if(storedData.entityId === entityId){
        // return to getData()
        return $q.resolve(storedData);
    }else{
        var entityDataPromise = dataAccessService.getEntityData(entityId).$promise;
      // return to getData()
      return  entityDataPromise.then(function (response) {
            storedData = response;
            return storedData ;
         });
         entityDataPromise['catch'](function(error) {
              //throw error;
         });
         entityDataPromise['finally'](function(done) {
             //do finally
         });
    }
 }
```

Be sure to inject `$q` in service.

In controller would be:

```
var myPromise = sharedDataService.getData($scope.entityId);
resolvePromise(myPromise, 'entityData');
```

Comment: $q is an object without resolve for me -- options are `all`, `defer`, `reject`, and `when`

Comment: not sure what you mean... it is a documented method

Comment: this article was helpful: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2735-q-when-is-the-missing-q-resolve-method-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Docs are more absolute and there is a resolve() .. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: `var deferred = $q.deferred;` then `deferred.resolve(storedData)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117429/discussion-between-user-8675309-and-charlietfl).